# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este código, tengo un archivo index.php, donde se encuentra el formulario para iniciar sesión.
El error que me da es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function login() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs...\admin\index.php:64 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs...\admin\index.php on line 64

index.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="email" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
            <label> Email</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="password" name="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required="required">
            <label> Contraseña</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button name="btnEntrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"> Entrar </button>
</form>
<?php

    include 'core/db.php';
    include 'modelo/usuarios.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnEntrar'])){

    $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    login($email, $password);

    }
?>
```

este es el archivo usuarios.php

```
public function login($email, $password){
    $resp=[];
    try{
        //VERIFICAMOS SI EXISTE EL USUARIO
        $sql="SELECT * FROM ahh_usuarios WHERE email = ?";
        $smt=$this->cn->prepare($sql);
        $smt->execute(array($email));
        $resp=$smt->fetch();

        //SI NO EXISTE MATAMOS LA OPERACIÓN
        if(!$resp) {
            echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php?e=1';</script>";
            die();
        }

        if(password_verify($password, $resp->password)){
            $_SESSION['LOGUEADO']=true;
            $_SESSION['USUARIO']=$resp;
            echo "<script>window.location = 'escritorio.php';</script>";

        }else{
            echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php?e=1';</script>";
            die();
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $resp;
}
```

Comment: `usuarios.php` debe ser una clase. Cómo se llama? Pegá el código completo de dicho archivo.

Comment: ya lo corregi, me faltaba esto $obj = new Usuarios();  $obj->login($email, $password);

Comment: Exacto, a eso quería llegar.